# C# Form - logIn WebSite

Tags: c#, php

I want to log in website from C# form, i find user textbox id and password textbox id, but i can't find log in button id.
what i should do when button has not id in website and i want to log in from C# form?

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("user_name").SetAttribute("value", textBox1.Text);
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("user_password").SetAttribute("value", textBox2.Text);
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("here i wont button id").InvokeMember("click");
```

Comment: what exactly you want???

Comment: I want to get some parameters about user from web page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you can't find something unique for that login button :

**Edit: Tested and Working**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //WebBrowser webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser();
            webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.facebook.com");

            webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(loaded);


        }


        private void loaded(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            var bro = sender as WebBrowser;
            var List = bro.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");



            foreach (HtmlElement Item in List)
            {
                String Value = Item.GetAttribute("value");
                if(Value != null && Value == "Log In")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(Value);

                    bro.Document.GetElementById("email").SetAttribute("value", "Some Email");
                    bro.Document.GetElementById("pass").SetAttribute("value", "Some Pass");

                    Item.InvokeMember("click");
                    // avoid Repetition
                    bro.DocumentCompleted -= new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(loaded);
                }
            }
        }
```

I Hope this helps.

Comment: I have error at "var List = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("<input>");"
screen -> http://oi42.tinypic.com/25f15yu.jpg

Comment: Sorry, replace <input> by 'input'

Comment: error :/ screen -> http://oi44.tinypic.com/21ahc49.jpg

Comment: You have to navigate for the url first ! webBrowser1.Navigate("URL HERE");

Comment: I have navigate from web browser properties, but i tried your method but don't working :/

Comment: Check the edits please.

Comment: In website login button has only type, value, class and style :/
i tried it has not error but don't working. nothing happend

Comment: screen http://oi39.tinypic.com/eu0s4w.jpg

Comment: Ok , check my edited example and replace "Sign in" with the value attribute in your HTML.

Comment: tried it but nothing happend

Comment: If you're trying that with facebook , i just tried it and it works. Just replace "Sign in" with "Log In"

Comment: it's my full code but don't working
code screen http://oi39.tinypic.com/ormmuv.jpg
form screen http://oi42.tinypic.com/av1kp5.jpg

Comment: You can't set the email and pass before the document completes loading, check my code and see where i set them.

Comment: it's working... you are great man, thank you very much :)) i want to be my friend, please contact me on fb.com/palelashvili